# Why is the open circuit voltage equal to Thevenin's Equivalent Voltage?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

[image]

When we are taught Thevenin's Theorem, we are taught that the equivalent voltage Vth is the voltage obtained at terminals A-B of the network with terminals A-B open circuited. But why is it true?

Comment: Look closely at the circuit on the right. If you place a voltmeter (which is ideally an open circuit) such that the red lead is on terminal A and the black lead is on terminal B, what voltage does the voltmeter read?

Answer (score 0):

It is true because if you connect a load across terminals A and B of either the circuit on the left or the circuit on the right, the voltage across the load and current through the load will be the same.  Thus the circuit on the right is equivalent to the circuit on the left with respect to the electrical input to a load connected between terminals A and B.

The beauty of this is you can connect different loads between A and B to the circuit on the right and quickly determine the voltage and current to the load, whereas you would need to more circuit analysis (KVL or KCL) to do the same for the circuit on the left.

Hope this helps.